# Using Azure CLI to enable Managed Identity Scopes for Web API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-cli&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-1

I get to the sectino where I need to use Azure CLI which I have never used before. I go through the commands in the tutorial and I get Insufficient privaledges. SO I went to users then assignments/roles and I am a global administrator for my account and I added application and also azure cloud admin and I still get the same error. Any ideas how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

As the portal doesn't have sufficient possibilities for this, you need to use the `Az CLI` to give any api permissions of managed identities to the app services or web apps as given in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-cli&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-1).

As per the above document, I tried to enable permissions in my environment once the web app is published and it worked as follows.

1. Added an identity provider (Microsoft) under `settings -> Authentication` in a web app by creating a new app registration with the current single tenant scope.

[image]

2. Once it is done, go to identity in a web app and enable system identity status to link the app service with Azure AD.
3. After that, execute the below CLI script to enable graph API permissions as given in the above document.

```bash
az login
webApp="caroap"
sprincipalId=$(az resource list -n $webApp --query [*].identity.principalId --out tsv)
graphResId=$(az ad sp list --display-name "Microsoft Graph" --query [0].id --out tsv)
APPRoleId=$(az ad sp list --display-name "Microsoft Graph" --query "[0].appRoles[?value=='User.Read.All' && contains(allowedMemberTypes, 'Application')].id" --output tsv)
uri=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/$spId/appRoleAssignments
body="{'principalId':'$sprincipalId','resourceId':'$graphResId','appRoleId':'$APPRoleId'}"
az rest --method post --uri $uri --body $body --headers "Content-Type=application/json"
```

*Output:*

[image]

Go to enterprise applications in Azure AD, filter with application type as *"managed identity"*. Check permissions under enterprise application. you will be able to see the enabled permissions as shown.

[image]

***Need to verify below:***

Verify if any specific RBAC roles or policies are in use: Your ability to act might at times be restricted by Azure policies or custom role-based access control (RBAC) roles.

You can also use Azure role-based access control (RBAC) to grant privileges to a service principal if you're seeking to authorize access to Azure App Configuration using Azure Active Directory.
Refer [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-app-configuration/concept-enable-rbac.md) for the detailed information regarding it.

Comment: Oddly enough in the app registration any permission I add shows up in the enterprise permissions already without even running the azure cli for that app permission (is that normal?). If the permission is in the enterprise app then the identity has permissions already right? The line you posted “ Go to enterprise applications in Azure AD, filter with application type as "managed identity".” has so much confusion for me because I don’t see a filter for managed identity on there.

Comment: I meant this regarding the filter type. [managed identity](https://i.imgur.com/aphWw78.png) @IrishRedneck

Comment: Ahhh I am dumb. BTW I use okta for my front end authentication and pass access tokens to my asp.net core web api which then uses jwt token validation for authorization. So in that one menu for the managed identity it says authentication enabled. I have that set to disable. Is that an issue you think? I just figured it wouldnt make sense having two authentication schemes going together and it would restrict access to my api completely.

Comment: Also I have not assigned my users to the app directly. Is that needed? I figure they are global admins so by default arent they included in the roles for all apps?